# Chromium in Launchpad but not in Applications

Tags: launchpad

I recently installed uTorrent on High Sierra but wasn't thinking and installed the Yahoo thing. The uTorrent installer says "Opera", but I ended up with a Chromium icon in my Launchpad. The problem is it isn't in my Applications folder.

I rebooted the laptop and Chromium started up on its own and when I opened Chrome I was notified that another application installed an extension. I removed it.

How do I get rid of this Chromium installation now? I have enabled the jiggle but no X appears.

Answer (score 6):

I know I just asked, but I figured it out and want to post the answer for others when they search for this same problem. Run the following in `Terminal`:

```
cd ~/Applications
rm -rf APP_NAME.app
```

**Note**: If the app name contains a space, place a `\` character before the space so it looks like this `/My\ Space`

I verified that I was removing the correct app first by renaming it then checking LaunchPad to confirm the change. Once I saw that I was actually changing it in LaunchPad I went ahead and deleted it with the `rm` command.

You can additionally write `rm -rf` (with a space after the `-rf`) and then drag n’ drop the application from the Finder window into the terminal window. This will paste the path to the application correctly (auto fix spaces, etc.). Then press enter. This will ensure you have the correct path and are deleting the correct application.

**Warning**: Do not press enter without a path after `rm -rf`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Thanks for sharing your solution! Can I suggest you expand on your answer a little (e.g. opening Terminal etc).

Comment: Is it really `/Users/username/Applications`? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I remember it as `/Applications`.

Comment: @ÖmerRıfatKuldaşlı it can be both

Comment: @ÖmerRıfatKuldaşlı `/Applications` is the same as the Applications folder in Finder. It seems, though, that `/Users/USERNAME/Applications` is an alternate location that isn't tied to the Applications folder but it is tied to LaunchPad. Since they don't show up in Finder, you can't simply drag them to the Trash.